# Renaming, move to a folder, and create folder

Tags: php, shell

I am taking over a website already build because the original programmer is not available anymore.

I need to rename files in a directory, then move the files to their own folder matching the file name, but if the folder does not exist I need to create the folder.

To rename the files I have this php code that it was using the original programmer of the website (Was tested and is working as expected, Let me clarify that the files are something like STV12543.htm and need to be 12543_Todays-Date.htm)

```
<?php 

function dirList ($directory, $prefijo )
{
  $results = array();
$handler = opendir($directory);

while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
    $comienzo = substr($file, 0, 3);
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $comienzo== $prefijo)
        $results[] = $file;
}
closedir($handler);
return $results;
}

$directory = "ws/archivos-cli/";
$prefijo = "STV";
$resultado = dirList($directory, $prefijo);
foreach($resultado as $file){
        $ultima_modificacion = filemtime($directory.$file);
        $ultima_modificacion = date("Y-m-d", $ultima_modificacion);
        $name = split('STV',$file);
        $name = split('.htm',$name[1]);
        $newname = $name[0].'_'.$ultima_modificacion.'.htm';
        //if (!file_exists($directory.$newname))
        rename($directory.$file, $directory.$newname);
}

?>
```

I guess I can call that scrip with a cron, but for moving files, I have a sh script

```
#!/bin/sh

source_dir='/ws/archivos-cli/' 
target_dir='/ws/archivos-cli/subfolders'
name_separator='_'

(
cd ${source_dir} || {
    echo "${source_dir} no existe!" ; exit 1
}
for i in `ls` ; do
    client_name="`echo ${i} | cut -f1 -d${name_separator}`"
    echo "-> Moving file [${i}] to [${target_dir}/${client_name}/] folder"
    mv -vf ${i} ${target_dir}/${client_name}/ || break
    echo
done
)
```

So, how can I combine them (the 2 scripts) and add the option to create the folder if not exists, based on the file name without the date?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might want to post this to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) first (maybe separately), or just look around for somebody else's code to do something similar. At least the shell code is extremely broken: [Parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), unnecessary subshell, and missing [quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) at least.

Comment: Thank you!, the PHP code was just tested and worked as expected, I would need to add the "move and create folder if not exists" part of the ecuation so I can ditch the shell code.
I will post in code review to see how is it. Thank you!